# Linking to a text field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get people that are not logged in to log in by linking them to the log in fields in the sidebar.

So far I managed to accomplish this:

```
<?php comment_form(array(must_log_in => sprintf(__('You must be <a href="#reg">logged in</a> to comment.')))); ?>
```

So I am using the `Login with AJAX` widget, or I could just place the plugin's template tag in there which is `<?php login_with_ajax() ?>`.  Right before the widget I have placed `<a name="reg"></a>`, so when they click the link to log in they get to where the log in form is, but they are not placed in the username field.  Is there a way (I doubt it) where I can place the focus in the username field?  That is to have a blinking cursor in there?

"It is not possible" is also an acceptable answer, so I can move onto my next problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming something like `<input type="text" id="username">`, you could use

`document.getElementById("username").focus();`

in JavaScript.